# Linux backup restore not working

Tags: linux, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I got errors yesterday from my Linux terminal, but I backed up my files from Linux and then uninstalled and reinstalled Linux.  Then, I am trying to restore the Linux files from the .tini file I got.  After waiting, the restore had an error so I tried again.  Still, the restore is giving me an error.  Please tell me how I can fix this.  My device is an Acer Chromebook.  Thank You!  This is the image of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try powerwashing. I had issues with my restoration post-powerwashing and I solved it by restarting my machine and giving it a couple of tries.

You may wish to take a look at crosh, I believe you can also restore your Crostini using that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting the chromebook? You can do this by doing `PowerButton+RefreshButton`.

If restarting it doesn't work (please try multiple times), try switching to a different ChromeOS channel.

You can do this by going into ChromeOS's settigs, then going to "About Chrome OS", go into "Additional Details", then click "Change Channel".

I would suggest switching to Beta if you are currently on Stable, as I'm pretty sure you do not have to powerwash.

If all fails, and you do not want to powerwash, I would suggest getting "Wicked Good Unarchiver" from the chrome webstore.

This can help you salvage needed files. (Like your home directory)